# How does github make my own repositories can be downloaded by anyone

Tags: git, github

I want to put a repository on github so that everyone can download it. Similar to https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard.git. I don’t need a `fork`, I can use `git clone https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard.git` to download it. But if someone `git clone my_repository`, there will be an inaccessible error.

My purpose is to use my repository as a sub-module of another software, so that when someone downloads software, they can also download this repository at the same time.

what should I do? thanks!

Comment: Check out https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/troubleshooting-cloning-errors

Comment: didn't making the repo public help?